# Assigning Arguments in Shell Scripts

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

So I new to shell scripts, and currently I have a sheLL I call to run my others it looks like this

```
  # RC Script Call 
if [ "$1" = "runrc" ]
then
    echo "RC folder Setup is running"
    echo ""
    sh ./RCFolderSetup.sh
fi

if [ "$2" = "runrc" ]
then
    echo "RC folder Setup is running"
    echo ""
    sh ./RCFolderSetup.sh
fi

if [ "$3" = "runrc" ]
then
    echo "RC folder Setup is running"
    echo ""
    sh ./RCFolderSetup.sh
fi

# Trunk Script Call 
if [ "$1" = "runtrunk" ]
then
    echo "Trunk folder Setup is running"
    echo ""
    sh ./TrunkFolderSetup.sh
fi

if [ "$2" = "runtrunk" ]
then
    echo "Trunk folder Setup is running"
    echo ""
    sh ./TrunkFolderSetup.sh
fi

if [ "$3" = "runtrunk" ]
then
    echo "Trunk folder Setup is running"
    echo ""
    sh ./TrunkFolderSetup.sh
fi

# Testing Script Call 
if [ "$1" = "runtest" ]
then
    echo "Test folder Setup/Push the files is running"
    echo ""
    sh ./TestingScript.sh
fi

if [ "$2" = "runtest" ]
then
    echo "Test folder Setup/Push the files is running"
    echo ""
    sh ./TestingScript.sh
fi

if [ "$3" = "runtest" ]
then
    echo "Test folder Setup/Push the files is running"
    echo ""
    sh ./TestingScript.sh
fi
```

As you can see I have to assign everything more than one value, My question is, is their an easier way to write this script out but still have it do the same thing

Comment: @Ric yeah i know what or is, that didnt work for me thats why i am here

Comment: @Ric `[ ]` is more portable and nothing here requires `[[ ]]`.

Comment: If you use `echo -e` you can just use one echo and add a `\n` to the end of the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a sane replacement would be

```
#!/bin/sh

# while the number of arguments is not zero    
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do

    # do the stuff for the first argument
    case "$1" in
        runrc)
            echo "RC folder Setup is running"
            echo ""
            sh ./RCFolderSetup.sh
            ;;
        runtrunk)
            echo "Trunk folder Setup is running"
            echo ""
            sh ./TrunkFolderSetup.sh
            ;;
        runtest)
            echo "Test folder Setup/Push the files is running"
            echo ""
            sh ./TestingScript.sh
            ;;
    esac

    # and shift the arguments back one so that $2 becomes $1, $3 becomes $2,
    # and so forth
    shift
done
```

If the order of execution is important (if it should be fixed even if the arguments are jumbled), this approach could be amended to

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
        runrc)
            do_runrc=yes
            ;;
        runtrunk)
            do_runtrunk=yes
            ;;
        runtest)
            do_runtest=yes
            ;;
    esac

    shift
done

if [ "$do_runrc" = yes ]; then
    echo "RC folder Setup is running"
    echo ""
    sh ./RCFolderSetup.sh
fi

if [ "$do_runtrunk" = yes ]; then
    echo "Trunk folder Setup is running"
    echo ""
    sh ./TrunkFolderSetup.sh

fi

if [ "$do_runtest" = yes ]; then
    echo "Test folder Setup/Push the files is running"
    echo ""
    sh ./TestingScript.sh
fi
```

Comment: Haha you were faster than me! `+1`.

Comment: I was just about to post the same :( +1

Comment: Hooray for speed typing! :D Well, it would have been surprising if I'd been the only one to think of this.

Answer (score 2):

Create a function for those `if` block like this:

```
checkArg() {
    if [ "$1" = "$2" ]; then
      echo "$3"
      echo 
      sh "$4"
   fi
}
```

Then call it as:

```
checkArg "$1" "runtrunk" "Trunk folder Setup is running" "./TrunkFolderSetup.sh"

checkArg "$2" "runtrunk" "Trunk folder Setup is running" "./TrunkFolderSetup.sh"

checkArg "$3" "runrc" "RC folder Setup is running" "./RCFolderSetup.sh"

## ...
## ...
```